# Tensorflow - Keras: Consider either turning off auto-sharding or switching the auto_shard_policy to DATA to shard this dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

While training a model in keras / tensorflow:

The code snippet:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
```

I got the below error / warning:

```
Consider either turning off auto-sharding or switching the auto_shard_policy to DATA to shard this dataset. You can do this by creating a new `tf.data.Options()` object then setting `options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = AutoShardPolicy.DATA` before applying the options object to the dataset via `dataset.with_options(options)`.
    2020-12-16 17:12:20.885741: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:127] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
    2020-12-16 17:12:20.905570: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 3593105000 Hz
    Epoch 1/40
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the first line of the error advises on the next steps, no?

Answer (score 27):

The error message here has newly arrived in `tensorflow 2.4.0`. While the error hints at a solution, it presupposes that your data is an object of the type `tf.data.Dataset`. There was previously no strict requirement to have your input data in this form (e.g. numpy arrays were fine), except now it seems to be a requirement with the distribute strategies (e.g `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`). In any event, there does not appear to be a way to avoid tensorflow's latest console-vomit without wrapping your data in a Dataset object..

So supposing your current code looks something like this:

```python
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = ... # awesome model definition

train_x, train_y = np.array(...), np.array(...)
val_x, val_y = np.array(...), np.array(...)

batch_size = 32
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))
```

It needs to be changed to look like this:

```python
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = ... # awesome model definition

train_x, train_y = np.array(...), np.array(...)
val_x, val_y = np.array(...), np.array(...)

# Wrap data in Dataset objects.
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))
val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_x, val_y))

# The batch size must now be set on the Dataset objects.
batch_size = 32
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)
val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size)

# Disable AutoShard.
options = tf.data.Options()
options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.OFF
train_data = train_data.with_options(options)
val_data = val_data.with_options(options)

model.fit(train_data, validation_data=val_data)
```

Note that if you don't set the batch size on the Dataset object, you'll get a cryptic error like this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/distribute.py", line 496, in get_static_batch_dim
    return output_shape.dims[0].value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: any chance you could explain a little what this AutoShard is doing?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm clueless on this. I guess you'll have to read about sharding here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/input

Comment: What if the original `train_data` Numpy array was accessed through a Keras batch generator using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`?

Comment: Can't help I'm afraid @Jivan. I got sick of each tensorflow release breaking my code, so I've stopped using it in favour of jax.